# What does the bottom of the brainstem to do with attention?

Tags: meaning

What did I miss in the passage? I am not good at biology.  I have no idea of the relation between the brainstem and attention.

> While some blame our collective tech addiction on personal failings,
> like weak willpower, Harris points a finger at the software itself.
> That itch to glance at our phone is a natural reaction to apps and
> websites engineered to get us scrolling as frequently as possible. The
> attention economy, which showers profits on companies that seize our
> focus, has kicked off what Harris calls ***a “race to the bottom of
> the brain stem.”*** “You could say that it’s my responsibility” to
> exert self-control when it comes to digital usage, he explains, “but
> that’s not acknowledging that there’s a thousand people on the other
> side of the screen whose job is to break down whatever responsibility
> I can maintain.” In short, we’ve lost control of our relationship with
> technology because technology has become better at controlling us.

[THE BINGE BREAKER](https://www.theatlantic.com/magazine/archive/2016/11/the-binge-breaker/501122/)

Comment: Did you do a search for the phrase? If so, what did you find?

Comment: What I found from many sources is it means 'the manipulation of instincts and feelings,' but  I couldn't find how that is related to the brainstem.

Comment: Not sure why this is posted to English SE? It's not a question about English, it's about biology (or neuropsychology).

Comment: Note that "race to the bottom" is an idiom (in U.S. English, at least) used to describe real or figurative competition in which rivals spur each other to engage in ever-worsening behavior (lowering their standards of fair play, dispensing with moral scruples, cheating with increasing brazenness) in pursuit of victory. It seems likely that "race to the bottom of the brain stem" is at one level a play on this idiom.

Answer (score 1):

This is an analogy between a race, in which competitors focus solely on the end point, and the way we think in response to stimuli. Although depending on some knowledge of brain function, the linguistic question is essentially about recognising analogy.

The attention economy represents the many ways in which companies stimulate our need to buy and contribute to their profits.

It does so by appealing to our emotions.

Our emotions can dominate critical thought, and that is why companies seek to manipulate them.

The brain stem plays an important role in our emotions:

> [Frontiers in Neuroanatomy](https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fnana.2017.00015/full)
>
> Emotions are mental and bodily responses that are deployed automatically when an organism recognizes that a situation warrants such a reaction. Due to humans’ intellectual capacities, human emotional reactions are not necessarily triggered by immediate (real) physical or social circumstances, but can also be precipitated by inferences, memories, beliefs or imaginings. Although human emotions can involve complex cognitive deliberations, their activating power fundamentally depends upon the modulation of arousal, motor control and somatosensation. Emotions are therefore regulated by a broad range of subcortical and cortical structures, with a critical role being played by subcortical nuclei in the pontine and midbrain tegmentum, as well as by autonomic and cardiorespiratory nuclei in the medulla.

The medulla is the base of the brain stem and influences automatic things such as heart rate and blood pressure. Above it are the pons and the midbrain, which deal with more emotional and thinking matters.

The companies therefore try to race down through our critical instincts to the more emotional and basic responses that are at the base, to stimulate buying by appealing to more automatic than reflective actions.

(Forgive my naively expressed neurophysiology; the details are unreliable but I believe the analogy stands)

Comment: Hence the 'appeal to our base nature' (with 'base' the ignoble sense). It fits nicely with the 'high = morally excellent' etc metaphor ... though I doubt it contributed to the origins of the metaphor.